# Why is my return value not properly recognized?

Tags: java

**MyClass.java**

```
protected LinkedBlockingDeque<JobSet> currentWork = new LinkedBlockingDeque<JobSet>();

public LinkedBlockingDeque<JobSet> getCurrentWork() {
    return currentWork;
}
```

**Usage**

```
public boolean completeAllWork(CompleteWorkRequest request) {
    for (JobSet jobSet : getCurrentWork()) {
        //if it's approved, find the workflow process it needs to go to next and put it there
        if (request.getApprovedJobSets().contains(jobSet.getUuid().toString())) {
            sendToNextWorkflowProcess(jobSet);
        } else {
            getCurrentWork().remove(jobSet);
            logger.info("Rejected JobSet: " + jobSet.getUuid());
        }
    }

    getWorkFromQueue();

    return true;
}
```

It's expecting a `JobSet` but getting an `Object`.  It seems clear to me that it's returning the proper object, so what did I miss?

```
Error: java: incompatible types
  required: com.production.model.JobSet
  found:    java.lang.Object
```

Comment: Can you share some of the body of the for loop?

Comment: Whats the error? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: You can't get the error you mention with the code you have shown

Comment: Might be, due to empty collection

Comment: I've included the full method code

Comment: You might want to avoid removing `jobSets` from your list while you're iterating over it.

Comment: Can you try with normal `for`?

Comment: You should use an iterator to remove objects from a list you're iterating. Wouldn't surprise me if it causes some interference when you're trying to read a value that just got removed.

Comment: @VinitPrajapati No, empty list will not enter the `for` loop.

Comment: @m0skit0 Actually after my comment, question updated.

Comment: @VinitPrajapati: Even so: if the list is empty, it will never get iterated in the first place.

Comment: Check your `request.getApprovedJobSets()` is it really a `List<JobSet>`. Also, remove via an `Iterator`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Please post that as an answer, switching to an Iterator solved the problem.

Comment: Can you just check your imports once? not sure if that can be issue but have a look once.

Comment: @Webnet: posted as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments: using an  `Iterator` should solve the problem. My guess is there is interference while iterating the list and simultaneously removing an item, causing the loop to read a deleted value.

Comment: Not using an iterator would cause a runtime error at most. The original, compile time error must have been caused by something else.

Comment: I was told to put it as an answer since appearantly it resolved the issue. However as @Joni pointed out: this couldn't have been the cause. It would be nice to see the current code so we can determine what actually caused it.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that one of your methods is declared to return a `LinkedBlockingDeque` instead of a `LinkedBlockingDeque<JobSet>`.

- Check the declared return types of `getApprovedJobSets()`.
- Look at the code in the method `getWorkFromQueue()`, perhaps the error is thrown there.

Also, does the compiler give any "unchecked type" or "raw type" warnings?

Answer (score 0):

*Actually, if I understand correctly, your error does not come from the return statement, but from the two lines in the else statement.*
*I think you should look at what that methods are returning and try to modify them*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the error that you mention from the code you have posted so far. This compiles without errors:

```
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.Collection;

class dummy {
    static class JobSet {public Object getUuid() {return null;}}
    static class CompleteWorkRequest {public Collection getApprovedJobSets() {return null;}};
    void getWorkFromQueue() {}
    void sendToNextWorkflowProcess(JobSet js) {}


    protected LinkedBlockingDeque<JobSet> currentWork = new LinkedBlockingDeque<JobSet>();

    public LinkedBlockingDeque<JobSet> getCurrentWork() {
        return currentWork;
    }

    public boolean completeAllWork(CompleteWorkRequest request) {
        for (JobSet jobSet : getCurrentWork()) {
            //if it's approved, find the workflow process it needs to go to next and put it there
            if (request.getApprovedJobSets().contains(jobSet.getUuid().toString())) {
                sendToNextWorkflowProcess(jobSet);
            } else {
                getCurrentWork().remove(jobSet);
                //logger.info("Rejected JobSet: " + jobSet.getUuid());
            }
        }

        getWorkFromQueue();

        return true;
    }
}
```